# list view using Custom alert and edit the name in android

Tags: android, alert

I have a ListView with ten names. I want to use a custom alert when I click on a name and I want it to be editable. In this code I'm only getting the ListView, not the custom alert.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public ListView mainListView;
    public ArrayAdapter listAdapter;
    final Context context = this;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find the ListView resource.
        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );
        // Create and populate a List of planet names.
        String[] planets = new String[] { "Allu", "Abin", "Bibin", "Aswathy",
        "Jibin", "Saran", "Jobin", "Neethu","ammu","Ram"};
        ArrayList planetList = new ArrayList();
        planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );

        // Create ArrayAdapter using the planet list.
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.simplerow, planetList);

        /*// Add more planets. If you passed a String[] instead of a List
        // into the ArrayAdapter constructor, you must not add more items.
        // Otherwise an exception will occur.
        listAdapter.add( "Ceres" );
        listAdapter.add( "Pluto" );
        listAdapter.add( "Haumea" );
        listAdapter.add( "Makemake" );
        listAdapter.add( "Eris" );*/

        // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView’s adapter.
        mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
        mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alert.setTitle("Alert Dialog With EditText"); //Set Alert dialog title here
                alert.setMessage("Edit Your Name Here"); //Message here

                // Set an EditText view to get user input
                final EditText input = new EditText(context);
                alert.setView(input);

                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // You will get as string input data in this variable.
                        // here we convert the input to a string and show in a toast.
                        String srt = input.getEditableText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(context,srt,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                //End of alert.setPositiveButton

                alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // Canceled.
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }); //End of alert.setNegativeButton
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: try to open a dialog with all the values of item of list which cliecked and update then.

Comment: Change the  “Allu”, “Abin”, “Bibin”, “Aswathy”,
“Jibin”, “Saran”, “Jobin”, “Neethu”,”ammu”,”Ram”  to  "Allu","Abin","Bibin", "Aswathy",
"Jibin", "Saran", "Jobin", "Neethu","ammu","Ram"  (You doesn't using double quoates.Please change all symbol to double quotes)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

you have an error in the appointment of the listener

```
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alert.setTitle("Alert Dialog With EditText"); //Set Alert dialog title here
                alert.setMessage("Edit Your Name Here"); //Message here

                final EditText input = new EditText(context);
                alert.setView(input);

                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        String srt = input.getEditableText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(context,srt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
                alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }); //End of alert.setNegativeButton
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

this worked

pay attention to the interface `OnItemClickListener`

which method you need to override and what you have written

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {

        /**
         * Callback method to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has
         * been clicked.
         * <p>
         * Implementers can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need
         * to access the data associated with the selected item.
         *
         * @param parent The AdapterView where the click happened.
         * @param view The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this
         *            will be a view provided by the adapter)
         * @param position The position of the view in the adapter.
         * @param id The row id of the item that was clicked.
         */
        void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id);
    }
```

to save you need to make such changes

```
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alert.setTitle("Alert Dialog With EditText"); //Set Alert dialog title here
            alert.setMessage("Edit Your Name Here"); //Message here

            final EditText input = new EditText(context);
            input.setText((String)planetList.get(position));
            alert.setView(input);

            alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    String srt = input.getEditableText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(context,srt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    planetList.set(position, srt);
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }); //End of alert.setNegativeButton
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

`planetList` make to final `final ArrayList planetList = new ArrayList();`

And yet, for better use of **generics** lists

Comment: How can i save the new name into the edited list view?

Comment: Is it possible to show selected list view value can be shown in custom alert  box before editing??   if yes please tell me how it is possible?

Comment: yes i want that text field was filled before editing